# How many archimedean ordered fields are there?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

This question is inspired by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39511/70180) answer: There it is claimed that 'all archimedean ordered fields are subfields of reals'. Also, that there is a non-archimedean ordered field for every cardinality greater than $|\Bbb R|$.

> How many archimedean ordered fields are there? I mean, are they finite?
>
> I think I read somewhere that $\Bbb Q$ is smallest ordered field. Also, [Dedekind completion](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Dedekind_Completion) of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$. Is this claim correct that 'if $\Bbb F$ is an archimedean ordered field, then Dedekind completion of $\Bbb F$ is $\Bbb R$?'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to isomorphism, there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ different archimedean ordered fields.  Indeed, every subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ is an archimedean ordered field, and no two different subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic as ordered fields (since each element is determined by the set of rational numbers less than it, which is preserved by any isomorphism of ordered fields).  Now let $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a set of $2^{\aleph_0}$ algebraically independent real numbers.  For any $S\subseteq B$, $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, and these subfields are all distinct.  This gives $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ non-isomorphic archimedean ordered fields.  Conversely, there can't be more than $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ such fields since there are only $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

As for your second question, since $\mathbb{R}$ is Dedekind-complete and any archimedean ordered field is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$, the Dedekind-completion of any archimedean ordered field is $\mathbb{R}$ (up to isomorphism).

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply.